# Third Normal Form in DBMS

Tags: database, normalization, database-normalization, 3nf, bcnf

I was just reading the definition of 3NF in DBMS, it states that:

The functional dependency X --> A is allowed if:
1. X is a super key.
2. A is part of some key.

I have 2 doubts:

a: I don't get the point of how is the second condition useful to remove the anomalies.Why have BCNF form, instead we can define 3NF form to not have the 2nd condition.

I get the point of removing the tranisitive dependency.
If Y --> Z and X is the primary key. Then there is  a transitive dependency as X --> Y --> Z means that we cant store values of (X,Y) unless we know Z.

b: Please explain how removing the 2nd condition in the 3NF would remove the anomalies and/or restrict redundancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"The functional dependency X --> A is allowed if: 1. X is a super key. 2. A is part of some key."*

The *second* condition of your definition is **wrong**. `A` should be a **non-prime** attribute (*i.e. it shouldn't be a part of the key to satisfy 3NF*). 
In fact better way to understand **3NF** is -
 *given a functional dependency `X->Y` **if** `Y` is a **non-prime** attribute then `X` **has to be** a **superkey**.*
(*Notice that this **ensures no transitive dependency***)
On the other hand **BCNF** is-
*for **every** functional dependency `X->Y` the left hand side (`X`) **has to be** a **superkey** (whether the right hand side(`Y)` is prime or not prime it doesn't matter)*
**Now for your first doubt**
 *"Why have BCNF form, instead we can define 3NF form to not have the 2nd condition?"*  Yes if you remove the second condition of 3NF (that is `Y` should be non-prime attribute) then it is equivalent to BCNF. But why will you want to do that? *There are times when you are not able to reduce a relation to BCNF ( **because it is not always possible to get a BCNF decomposition that is dependency preserving** ) then reducing it to 3NF is at least better then letting it to be in 2NF*
**For example**-

```
R=(J,K,L)
F={JK->L,L->K}
```

Here we have 2 candidate keys - `JK` and `JL` and `R` is not in **BCNF**. Any decomposition of `R` will fail to preserve `JK->L`. This implies that testing for `JK->L` requires a join. So there are situations where -

- BCNF is not dependency preserving, and
- efficient checking for functional dependency violation on updates is important

**Solution**: define a weaker normal form, called 3NF. **There is always a lossless-join, dependency-preserving decomposition into 3NF.** 

I don’t really get your **second** doubt - *"how...3NF would remove the anomalies and/or restrict redundancy"*. 3NF would remove redundancy buy removing any transitive dependency!

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437957/difference-between-3nf-and-bcnf-in-simple-terms-must-be-able-to-explain-to-an-8) might be of some help too.