# Creating Functional Dependencies and identifying Normal Forms from ER Diagram

Tags: entity-relationship, functional-dependencies, 3nf, bcnf

I am an ICS student and I have been given two questions.

> 1.) List all the Functional Dependencies that hold for the database.
>
> 2.) For each relation in your relational schema write down whether the relation is in BCNF or 3NF and if not give a violating FD.

I'm just having problems understanding the relationship between functional dependencies and the ER Diagram. I've watched a few videos online but I'm still getting stuck on how to answer the two above questions and would appreciate some help in finding the right direction.

Below is an ER diagram and I was hoping someone could give some examples on how to start from here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- For each entity set (e.g. `Department`), each attribute is an FD (e.g. `Department Name -> Location`).
- For each relationship set (e.g. `Offers`), there's an FD from the combination of keys of "many" entities to each of the keys of "one" entities (e.g. `Course_ID -> Department Name`)

Comment: Thank you, that makes FD's much clearer, however I still don't get the differences between BCNF and 3NF

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437957/difference-between-3nf-and-bcnf-in-simple-terms-must-be-able-to-explain-to-an-8