# Constructing decomposition of a table into 3NF

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I need to construct a decomposition of this table into relations in 3NF,

```
EMPLOYEE(SSN, FName, LName, Nickname, Project, Team)
```

with the following set F of functional dependencies:

```
SSN→FName
SSN→LName
FName, LName→SSN
FName→Nickname
SSN→Project
SSN→Team
Team→Project
```

What I came up with is this below, but I'm not sure if I'm approaching this the right way:

I would remove

```
Team→Project
```

because it is not needed since you can access Project through SSN so I end up with:

```
SSN→FName LName Project, Team, FName→Nickname
```

I'm also really not understanding the difference between 3NF and BCNF. I've read articles and went thought some questions in this site, but I really need to understand it in layman's terms.

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: Without directly answering your specific questions: I wouldn't remove Team -> Project; rather, remove SSN - > Project, that can be obtained from SSN -> Team and Team -> Project. Then, why do FName, LName -> SSN? Is there only one John Doe in the table?

Comment: Also: Google is your friend (if you are in a country where Google is not blocked). Here is one of the first hits - it points back to SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437957/difference-between-3nf-and-bcnf-in-simple-terms-must-be-able-to-explain-to-an-8