# How to restrict values in a column based on values from another column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, enums, foreign-keys, constraints

I would like to prevent a mismatch between `course_code` and `course_name`when inserting values to the table below.

```
CREATE TABLE course (
    course_id    INT4 NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    course_code  CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    course_name  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
```

For both I created an enumeration (see below), now I want to link `'C101'` to `'Computer Science'` etc.

```
CREATE TYPE e_course_code AS ENUM (
    'C101',
    'B102',
    'E103',
    'V104',
    'A105',
    'E104'
);

CREATE TYPE e_course_name AS ENUM (
    'Computer Science',
    'Business Information Management',
    'Electronics',
    'Visual Programming',
    'Audio Technology',
    'Engineering'
);
```

Is it possible to link specified (enumerated) values for two (or even more) columns? Something that returns an error message when inserting a `course_code` and `course_name` that do not match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fast and reliable way to implement **what you ask in the title** is a [**`FOREIGN KEY`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) constraint with **`MATCH FULL`**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE course (
  course_code varchar(4) PRIMARY KEY
, course_name text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE some_other_table (
  some_other_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, course_code   varchar(4)
, course_name   text
, -- more columns
, CONSTRAINT course_fk FOREIGN KEY (course_code, course_name)
                  REFERENCES course(course_code, course_name) MATCH FULL
);
```

See:

- [MATCH FULL vs MATCH SIMPLE in foreign key constraints](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/71508/3684)

However, `some_other_table.course_name` would be completely redundant, and the clean implementation would be the normalized form instead:

```sql
CREATE TABLE some_other_table (
  some_other_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, course_code   varchar(4)
, -- more columns?
, CONSTRAINT course_fk FOREIGN KEY (course_code) REFERENCES course(course_code)
);
```

Or you add `course_id` as PK to the `course` table and use that as FK column.

You can always add a [`VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) to *display* `course_name` additionally.

Aside: Never use the type `char` or `char(n)`. See:

- [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve this (as i see it) would make two separate tables- one with id and code, another with code and name. See this question - [Difference between 3NF and BCNF in simple terms (must be able to explain to an 8-year old)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437957/difference-between-3nf-and-bcnf-in-simple-terms-must-be-able-to-explain-to-an-8) - the example in the answer is similar to your problem.