# Converting 3NF to BCNF

Tags: database-design, database-normalization, bcnf

I am trying to change my table from Third Normal Form to BCNF but not sure I understand the concept entirely.

I managed to work through 1NF, 2NF and 3NF (I think), but need help getting it to BCNF.

I have

```
**Students Table**

ID -- First Name -- Last Name -- Age
1  --   Joe      --   Jugg    -- 22
2  --   Ben      --   March   -- 23
3  --   Sally    -- Rainbow   -- 19



**StudentCourse Table**

ID -- Course Title -- Grade
1  -- Math         -- A
1  -- Physics      -- B
2  -- Math         -- C
3  -- Music        -- A


**Courses Table**

Course Title -- Course Fee -- Qualification -- Lecturer
Math         -- £1900      -- Advanced Level -- 2
Physics      -- £2300      -- Diploma        -- 1
Music        -- £1200      -- Certificate    -- 3



**Lecturers Table** 


Lecturer ID -- Lecturer Name
1           --  James Thomas
2           -- Harry Todd
3           -- Rachel Adam
```

I appriciate ANY help and would appriciate if you could explain the concept to me so I can understand, thanks.

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite your textbook with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you have shown no research or other effort. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following your textbook with justification & ask 1 specific question re the first place you are stuck. PS All the parts are SO duplicates. "Any help" is not a valid SO question. You don't give anything needed to solve this so it seems you don't know very basics. Textbook.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there's enough information there to determine how to reach BCNF from 3NF. We need to know something about the [functional dependencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency) between columns within tables in order to extrapolate [candidate keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candidate_key) and [super keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superkey). It doesn't help that the tables all have information that doesn't appear in multiple rows, with the exception of `StudentCourse` which already meets BCNF.

Looking at the data, we can postulate on the functional dependencies for the purposes of a working example. This doesn't mean the answer I'm providing is correct, but will give some insight given presumptions.

Let us presume that:

- Course Titles taught by a particular Lecturer are always taught at the same Qualification level
- All Certificates have a £1200 fee
- All Advanced Level Qualifications have a £1900 fee
- All Diplomas have a £2300 fee

Let us also presume that the `Courses` table has the following rows (note the additional fourth row):

```
Course Title -- Course Fee -- Qualification -- Lecturer
Math         -- £1900      -- Advanced Level -- 2
Physics      -- £2300      -- Diploma        -- 1
Music        -- £1200      -- Certificate    -- 3
Music        -- £1900      -- Advanced Level -- 1
```

Here we have a case of two functional dependencies in the table:

- Candidate Key #1 = (`Course Title, Lecturer`) -> (`Course Fee, Qualification`)
- Candidate Key #2 = (`Qualification`) -> (`Course Fee`)

If we want to change the Course Fee for Advanced Level Qualification to £2000, then because we have to update two rows in the `Courses` table, we encounter an [update anomoly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Objectives) - this is a violation of BCNF. We should only ever have to update one row in *some* table.

In order to meet BCNF, we need to create a new `Qualification` table, like so:

```
Qualification  -- Course Fee
Certificate    -- £1200
Advanced Level -- £1900
Diploma        -- £2300
```

...and in conjunction with that new table, we change the `Courses` table to the following:

```
Course Title -- Qualification -- Lecturer
Math         -- Advanced Level -- 2
Physics      -- Diploma        -- 1
Music        -- Certificate    -- 3
Music        -- Advanced Level -- 4
```

We now meet BCNF, as we no longer have a second candidate key (`Qualification -> CourseFee`) in the `Courses` table, and are able to perform our update on a single row.

---

You may find further useful information in the following links:

- [Difference between 3NF and BCNF in simple terms (must be able to explain to an 8-year old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437957/difference-between-3nf-and-bcnf-in-simple-terms-must-be-able-to-explain-to-an-8) (StackOverflow question with high votes)
- [External link that has a working example of data transforming from 1NF > 2NF > 3NF > BCNF > 4NF > 5NF](http://www.questionsolves.com/Website-Content/Normalization.php)