# Normalize a simple library system

Tags: database, database-normalization

In this question I have to normalize this database but I can't understand all the attributes.
For example, what are **Max-Num-Book** and why there are **Loan-status** and **loan-period**
in the relation "
***Max-reserved-book*** "?
Can any one help :) ?

[image]

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear from the question that `Max-Reserved-Book` is where information relating to book reservations is stored.

Reservations in this context would mean intent to loan, i.e. when do you want to loan the book (`Date-Reserved`) and for how long (`Loan-Period`).

`Max-Num-Book` appears to refer to the quantity of copies reserved, as the question states 'a person may borrow more than one book at a time.' It initially seemed like it might be a book/row identifier or a foreign key (as it's similar to the table name), but the `ISBN` field is probably intended for that use (possibly making a foreign key unnecessary).

Comment: This sounds great. So does moving the `Max-Num-Book` attribute to the `Catalogued-Book` relation solve the problem?
I believe that in that case, the schema will be satisfying 3NF. Is that right or I am missing something?

Comment: Assuming that `Max-Num-Book` is indeed the number of books to be reserved, why do you think moving that would satisfy 3NF? As general guidance, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437957/difference-between-3nf-and-bcnf-in-simple-terms-must-be-able-to-explain-to-an-8) are some good explanations for how to get to BCNF.